# Should I run an ANOVA between groups on each question from a questionnaire?

Tags: anova, multivariate-analysis, survey

I have asked one group of participants their views on 2 different forms of recruitment. They answer 19 identical Likert scale questions for each form, of the 19 questions there are 5 themes.

My idea was to an ANOVA for each question to determine whether there is a difference in opinions between the two forms of recruitment. Does this seem right?

Additionally, I am also looking at different demographics (i.e., gender, age etc) how do I go about testing whether these have an impact on the scores between the two?

Comment: There is an issue of multiple testing.